# Egrep results are current command and grabage

Tags: linux, grep

Im trying to egrep lines that contain nothing but a single occurrence of "Hihihihihihihi!", with arbitrarily many 'hi's

Here is what I write

```
egrep "^Hi(hi)*!$" myfile.txt
```

But it didn't work. After pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, the command was displayed again:

```
 egrep "^Hi(hi)*myfile.txt" mayflies.txt
```

Anyone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it actually show your command again, or does it show `egrep "^Hi(hi)*myfile.txt" myfile.txt` instead?

Comment: oh sorry. it actually shows egrep "^Hi(hi)*myfile.txt" mayflies.txt      I didn't noticed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell is interpreting `!$` to substitute the last argument of the previous commend.

To disable these shell substitutions, change the double quotes to single quotes.

```
egrep '^Hi(hi)*!$' myfile.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use the `-x` switch to match only whole lines, obviating the need for the `^` and `$` characters, and thus avoiding the fatal `!$` argument substitution:

```
egrep -x "Hi(hi)*!" myfile.txt
```

Comment: Did you test this?  My tests show single quotes are not enough quoting.  You need a backslash.

Comment: @MAP Yep, works fine here. `egrep '^Hi(hi)*!$' myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what shell, but I suspect the problem you have is that the exclamation mark (`!`) is extra special to the shell.  You need to escape that:

```
egrep "^Hi(hi)*\!$" myfile.txt
```

Should work in most shells where that's true.

Changing the double quotes to single quotes is not enough for all shells, the exclamation is still special inside single quotes.  I just tested all this in the tcsh, other shells will have differences.

Answer (score 1):

try it with single quotes. I think the $ is being interpreted by BASH as something, not sure what:

```
egrep '^Hi(hi)*!$' myfile.txt
```

Comment: Did you test this? My tests show single quotes are not enough quoting. You need a backslash.